# Can FFmpeg convert mp3 files into m4a in full, i.e. with both audio and video streams (jpeg cover) copied?

Tags: ffmpeg, mp3, m4a

I use Zeranoe build of FFmpeg. It converts mp3 files into m4a files just fine, as far as the audio stream is concerned, but I can't figure out a way to keep the songs album cover jpeg, which ffmpeg for some reason recognizes as

```
Stream #0:1: Video: mjpeg, yuvj420p, 200x200 [SAR 120:120 DAR 1:1]
```

included into the `output.m4a` file. When I use the following command line:

```
ffmpeg.exe -i 09.mp3 -map 0 -codec:a libvo_aacenc -ab 320k -ar 44100 -ac 2 -codec:v copy output.m4a
```

I get the `no tag, codec not currently in the container` error. And yet, when I run ffprobe with a `.m4a` file ctreated by iTunes, there it is:

```
Stream #0:1: Video: mjpeg, yuvj420p, 350x350 [SAR 72:72 DAR 1:1]
```

So, is there a way to copy the songs cover as well with ffmpeg conversion?

Comment: Please note that, according to [FFmpeg wiki](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/HighQualityAudio), **libvo_aacenc** is the worst AAC encoder(and even the worst audio encoder). Do NOT use **libvo_aacenc** in any circumstances. Instead, use **libfdk_aac** if possible (FFmpeg with libfdk_aac library is **unredistributable**, you have to build FFmpeg with libfdk_aac by yourself, ), **libfaac** is also acceptable if encoding with high bitrate.

Answer (score 7):

As far as I'm concerned, there's no easy way to tell FFmpeg to set the album artwork for an MP4 container, which you'd typically use for AAC audio (`.m4a`). You can however use [AtomicParsley](http://atomicparsley.sourceforge.net/) to add the artwork later, via command line.

Here's how you can install AtomicParsley:

- All operating systems have binaries from [the SourceForge page](https://sourceforge.net/projects/atomicparsley/files/atomicparsley/)
- Linux distributions might have it in the packages, i.e. `apt-get install atomicparsley`
- OS X through [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) with `brew install atomicparsley`

But first, we'll need to extract the artwork, e.g. as a JPEG file:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp3 artwork.jpg
```

We can then use AtomicParsley to add the album artwork:

```
AtomicParsley output.m4a --artwork artwork.jpg
```

This will not overwrite the original file but create a temporary file instead, e.g. `output-temp-15274.m4a`. If you want the original to be overwritten, add the `--overWrite` option to the command, e.g.:

```
AtomicParsley output.m4a --artwork artwork.jpg --overWrite
```

And voilà:

> [image]

Comment: Great idea, slhck! Actually, I switched to qaac command line for mp3->m4a conversion. As an option it allows for artwork to be imported into the m4a on the spot.

Comment: That's nice. I'm really not sure how to get FFmpeg to copy the artwork, there are no resources on this AFAIK and copying the video bitstream won't do. You can post your own solution as an answer here if you like, by the way.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this answer is coming a bit late but for those who are interested you can now keep all the streams only with ffmpeg like this:

```sh
# single file
ffmpeg -nostdin -i /path/to/input.flac -c:a alac -c:v copy /path/to/output.m4a 
# all the .flac files in the folder
for m in *.flac; do ffmpeg -nostdin -i "$m" -c:a alac -c:v copy "${m%.*}.m4a"; done
```

For more information, here's the input/output streams:

**Input:**

```
Stream #0:0: Audio: flac, 44100 Hz, stereo, s16
Stream #0:1: Video: mjpeg, yuvj444p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 800x800 [SAR 96:96 DAR 1:1], 90k tbr, 90k tbn, 90k tbc
```

**Output:**

```
Stream #0:0(und): Audio: alac (alac / 0x63616C61), 44100 Hz, stereo, s16p, 888 kb/s (default)
Stream #0:1: Video: mjpeg, yuvj444p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 800x800 [SAR 96:96 DAR 1:1], 90k tbr, 90k tbn, 90k tbc
```

Answer (score 0):

Useful Windows batch file:

```
@ECHO OFF
REM Extracting album cover art and resizing to 300x300 into temporary file in PNG format
REM because FFMPEG can’t handle properly cover art directly...
ffmpeg -i %1 -an -vcodec png -vf scale=300:-1 __arttemp__.png -y
REM timeout 30

REM Converting audio to AAC LLC into .M4A container (Apple "Signed")
REM The FFMPEG does not apply LowPass filter, but there is not so 
REM much control over other parameters, but in tests was the righest
REM VBR rate (350~400 Kbps)...
ffmpeg -i %1 -acodec aac -ab 512k -ac 2 -vn %2 -y
REM timeout 30

REM Applying already cover art image extracted from original file
REM with this new "AtomicParsley"...
AtomicParsley %2 --artwork __arttemp__.png --overWrite
REM timeout 30

REM Deleting temporary cover art file...
del __arttemp__.jpg 
REM timeout 30
```

Answer (score 0):

FFmpeg has an [open issue](//trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/2798) on this functionality. In the meantime, covers
can be added with the [TagEditor project](//github.com/Martchus/tageditor). To add:

```
tageditor -s cover=ju.jpg --max-padding 100000 -f ki.m4a
```

To remove:

```
tageditor -s cover= --max-padding 100000 -f ki.m4a
```