# Embedding artwork with FFmpeg during FLAC to ALAC conversion

Tags: ffmpeg, audio-conversion

How does one embed artwork during FLAC → ALAC conversion?

```
ffmpeg -i track.flac -acodec alac track.m4a
```

transfers metadata but not artwork.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think FFmpeg can't do that – M4A files store metadata in a strange way compared to FLAC, or MP3, or OGG. You can, however, use AtomicParsley as detailed in [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/524120/180990) to a very similar question. In summary:

```
ffmpeg -i input.flac -vn -c:a alac output.m4a cover.jpg
AtomicParsley output.m4a --artwork cover.jpg --overWrite
```

Comment: Is there a way to compel ffmpeg to dump the image file without converting it, no matter the format? (give us a png if the stream is png, and a jpeg if the stream is jpeg)